# Set td background color in jquery when td id's are known

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a jquery function which gets the id value of td's whose checkboxes are checked.
I need to color those td's. I have written this function which does not give me any error but does not color the td's also..

Here is the function:

```
$('#custom-interval-tbl td').each(function() {
 $(this).find('input:checkbox:checked').each(function() {      
    var tdId= $(this).attr("id");
    var tdElement = $("#custom-interval-tbl td").eq(tdId); 
    console.log("TD Element"+tdElement);        
    tdElement.css({background:"#333333"});
    });
});
```

Can someone please tell me what mistake am I doing?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[jsFiddle DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/9LAwB/1/)

The problem is you're using `.eq()` (which is index-based), but you're giving it the `id` of the checkbox.

On a side note, don't use :text / :checkbox / etc, these are deprecated within jQuery, and it is better to use native `[type="checkbox"]`, etc.

```
$('#custom-interval-tbl td').each(function() {
    $(this).find('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').each(function() {
        // You don't need to find out ID or anything.
        // Just go up to the closest <td> and give it the background

        var tdElement = $(this).closest('td');     
        tdElement.css({ background : "#333333" });
    });
});​
```

Comment: Thanks so much. Worked like a charm!

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem here is that `this` inside the second function refers to the `checkbox`, not to the `td`. Try this:

```
$('#custom-interval-tbl td').each(function() {
 $(this).find('input:checkbox:checked').each(function() {      
    var tdElement = $(this).parent("td");
    console.log("TD Element"+tdElement);        
    tdElement.css({background:"#333333"});
    });
});
```